# How to generate a new dataframe with concrete information of an existing one

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe from an existing one, generating two new columns ("topic" and "num") with information of the column "total" from the old dataframe.

This is the old dataframe where I want to take the info from:

```
d = {'username': ['low_bu', 'kik', 'serg'],
     'total': ['topic:tele,num:3,randomnums,topic:ordena,num:2','topic:pc,num:5,morenums,topic:ordena,num:3,things,topic:tele,num:4','topic:pc,num:2,sas,topic:ordena,num:3,rr,topic:other,num:4']
     }
d = pd.DataFrame(d)
d

   username         total
0   low_bu    topic:tele,num:3,randomnums,topic:ordena,num:2
1   kik       topic:pc,num:5,morenums,topic:ordena,num:3,things,topic:tele,num:4
2   serg      topic:pc,num:2,sas,topic:ordena,num:3,rr,topic:other,num:10
```

This is the expected results of the new dataframe (d_new):

```
username  topic   num
 low_bu    tele     3
 low_bu    ordena   2
 kik       pc       5
 kik       ordena   3
 kik       tele     4
 serg      pc       2
 serg      ordena   3
 serg      other    10
```

I have tried this approach but I am getting an error and anyway I think the code isn't exactly the one I am looking for:

```
d_new = {}
d_new = pd.DataFrame(d_new)    
d_new = d['username'].copy 
d_new['topic'] = d.total.str.split('topic:').str[1].str.split(',').str[0]
d_new['num'] = d.total.str.split('num:').str[1].str.split(',').str[0]
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What do you think the code is actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try regex to extract it the way you want, like the example below:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'username': ['low_bu', 'kik', 'serg'],
     'total': ['topic:tele,num:3,randomnums,topic:ordena,num:2','topic:pc,num:5,morenums,topic:ordena,num:3,things,topic:tele,num:4','topic:pc,num:2,sas,topic:ordena,num:3,rr,topic:other,num:4']
     }
d = pd.DataFrame(d)

# extract topics from total column
topics = d.set_index('username').total.str.extractall(r'topic:([^,]*)')
# extract nums from total column
nums = d.set_index('username').total.str.extractall(r'num:([^,]*)')

# generate a new data in the multi array form
# [[username, topic, num], [username, topic, num]] ...
data = []
for username in d.username.unique():
    for topic, num in zip(topics[0][username], nums[0][username]):
        data.append([username, topic, num])

d_new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns='username,topic,num'.split(','))
print(d_new)
  username   topic num
0   low_bu    tele   3
1   low_bu  ordena   2
2      kik      pc   5
3      kik  ordena   3
4      kik    tele   4
5     serg      pc   2
6     serg  ordena   3
7     serg   other   4
```

Learn more about Regex here: https://regexone.com

It is really useful for extracting text.

This website is also very useful for testing your regex: https://regex101.com